# Pass the id via getJson of the item selected in a select

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a select:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.DataTextField, Model, "Please select", new { id="selected-contract"}) %>
```

and on change I am calling an action via $.getJSON:

```
   $("#selected-contract").change(function () {

       $.getJSON("/Contract/List", [WHAT GOES HERE] ,updateList);

   });
```

The bit I am struggling with is passing back the ID of the item selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work this out:

```
$("#selected-contract").change(function () {
  $.getJSON("/Contract/List", { id: $("#selected-contract").val() }, updateList);
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you have works, but you can shorten it a bit using `this` inside the handler, for example:

```
$("#selected-contract").change(function () {
  $.getJSON("/Contract/List", { id: $(this).val() }, updateList);
});
```

It just saves you selecting the element all over again :)